# Remove grizzly2 http exceptions from logs using jersey test

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, grizzly, jersey-test-framework

I am using Jersey test framework and using grizzly2 as servlet container for running the tests.
Inside my tested resource I have logger, and for example I am logging when catching exceptions inside my logic(log.error("My Error") ). I can see this output when compiling my application and running tests (mvn clean install - run my tests as well).
Can I turn it off some how or prevent from the logs to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the log config file with "turn off ERROR "